# How do you technically save how many people have visited a certain URL or a certain post?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a forum app using Django as a backend and React as a front end. I want to find out how many people have visited a post created by a user so that I can store as views and list the posts according to popularity.

I am just a student and I have no experience with live websites, so I'm wondering if it is okay to just save a user at componentdidmount life cycle? But I'm afraid it'd make the same user be counted as many as he visits and the post creator will be able to increase his post's popularity by just spamming his website.

Comment: You find a decent analytics package (either hosted or something you can install on your own server), and then you use that. Don't waste time on reinventing a wheel that's already been built and extensively tested by others. Just use what they made. (and that goes for any kind of complex functionality, really: you're almost _certainly_ not the first person to need it: look around for open source, or free, solutions before you even start thinking "maybe I should write this myself")

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for the suggestions. I just thought it would be easy to create and saving data in the backend by what I create would be a lot easier. But I'll find for a good analytics tool that goes well with my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you implement this on the backend, not the front end. I don't know Django well, but there should be some way to know whether that particular post is getting requested. At that point, you'll want to increment the counter for that post.

The problem of course is determining which "views" count as real views. Was it the poster? Was it a robot? Was it a spider? Was it a scraper? Was it the same person who is not the poster viewing it many times?

I wouldn't say this last part is not an easy thing to implement, and would probably take some trial and error before finding the right conditions to get your metrics "right".

As @Mike suggests above, there are many analytics packages which use sophisticated algorithms to determine "realness", and you may be able to use this data. My understanding is that you want to actually apply the data to sorting and UI for your app, not just view it on the dashboard of your analytics tool. I've never tried to look for one that supports an API to discover what you're interested in programmatically, but they all probably allow you do download structured data about your traffic. The problem with the latter approach is that creates a delay and a manual step (always something to try to avoid imo).

Comment: But wouldn't taking the data of the visitors to the backend a long and tiring process for the users? I thought it'd take more data to access forth and back between backend and frontend, so I just assumed that it'd be best to process such data in the frontend by means of cookies, local storage, or even sessions and only carry the counter to the backend. So this way, wouldn't we be able to keep the data sent to the backend minimal?